# Proving rank inequalities of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I am given linear maps S and T and need to prove the four things.

For the first two examples should I consider the subsets and dimensions of the vector spaces and then use the rank-nullity theorem?
Also for (ii), if Rank(S)=r, then Im(S) is spanned by r vectors right?

[image]

Comment: When I did this question last year, I found it really helpful to draw a picture of the vector spaces and subspaces to help you get a good intuition for what was going on between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

(i) What is the definition of rank?

(ii) Can you translate the assertion $Rank(A)<Rank(B)$ into an assertion about the kernels of $A$ and $B$? How are the kernels of $TS$ and $S$ related?

(iii) Can you find a bijection between the kernels of $TS$ and $T$? How does this help?

(iv) Can you find a bijection between the images of $TS$ and $S$?

"Also for (ii), if Rank(S)=r, then Im(S) is spanned by r vectors right?" - yes. More precisely, the space $Im(S)$ has dimension $r$ as a vector space, and so it is possible to find $r$ linearly independent vectors whose span is $Im(S)$ but it is not possible to find $r+1$ such vectors.